# Custom grunt-modernizr with non-core detects

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, modernizr, getusermedia

Since the day I discovered [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/), I use it for all my front-end projects.

It includes grunt-modernizr that - at least I think - download the library and compiles it on the fly when I call the build task

```
grunt build
```

But I have a small problem : by defaults, it does not include the "non-core detects" that we can see online here : [modernizr custom builder](http://modernizr.com/download/)

Here is my grunt-modernizr task config (part of the Gruntfile.js file) :

```
modernizr: {
    devFile: '<%= yeoman.app %>/components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
    outputFile: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
    extra: {
        'shiv' : true,
        'printshiv' : false,
        'load' : true,
        'mq' : false,
        'cssclasses' : true
    },
    extensibility: {
        'addtest': true,
        'prefixed': false,
        'teststyles': false,
        'testprops': false,
        'testallprops': false,
        'hasevents': false,
        'prefixes': false,
        'domprefixes': false
    },
    files: [
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
        '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/vendor/*'
    ],
    uglify: true
}
```

In fact I would like to use Modernizr.getusermedia, but as a non-core feature, it is not defined...
Because the grunt-modernizr config does not seem to allow the non-core detects inclusion.

Any idea about this point?

**EDIT**: the modernizr task does not work anymore ; even when I remove the "extra" and "extensibility" properties...

```
Running "modernizr" task

Enabled Extras
>> shiv
>> load
>> cssclasses

Looking for Modernizr references

in dist/styles/main.min.css
>> svg
>> input

Downloading source files
cache modernizr-latest.js
cache modernizr.load.1.5.4.js

>> Generating a custom Modernizr build
Fatal error: Invalid regular expression: /TEST__flexbox']=function(){return testPropsAll('flexWrap');};tests['flexboxlegacy__/: Unterminated character class
```

Comment: unless you manually edited the modernizr file, you should open up a bug with the grunt-modernizr github issue tracker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, check out [stu cox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1306301/stu-cox)'s answer [here](https://github.com/Modernizr/grunt-modernizr/issues/28)

essentially,

> either use the matchCommunityTests config flag to let grunt-modernizr
>   find references to non-core tests in your code, or name them
>   explicitly in your tests config

Comment: I didn't know this property, thanks ! But I have another error, I've updated my topic with the problem !

Answer (score 3):

At the time this question was asked, the most recent version of `grunt-modernizr` would have been 0.4.1. Assuming that the OP was using the most recent version:

### Adding community tests in version 0.4.1

The [README](https://github.com/Modernizr/grunt-modernizr/tree/c46acc37c90779bbf5e713c300df864e29e69c91#optional) shows two (optional) options of interest:

> **`tests` (Array)**
>
> Define any tests you want to implicitly include. Test names are lowercased, separated by underscores (if needed). Check out the full set of test options [here](https://github.com/Modernizr/grunt-modernizr/blob/e23fb3d95feab1f3e168604f696b59b4a16dc7c2/lib/customappr.js#L2-111).

And:

> **`matchCommunityTests` (Boolean)**
>
> When `parseFiles` = `true`, setting this boolean to true will attempt to match user-contributed tests. Check out the full set of community tests [here](https://github.com/Modernizr/modernizr.com/blob/cc07084e9b4d35be1e12cc35b5f5d85722021384/i/js/modulizr.js#L15-L157)

You will notice that the list of available tests that one can add to the `tests` array includes both core and community tests. Thus, if you want to explicitly include particular community tests, you can enumerate them in the `tests` array option. For example:

```
// This would be in a larger config file
tests: ["a_download", "css_remunit"]
```

But if you have `parseFiles` set to true and want `grunt-modernizr` to detect any community tests that you have, you can set `matchCommunityTests` to true.

The posted config for `grunt-modernizr` does not included either of the options, and if the OP wanted to use `Modernizr.getusermedia`, they could simply set the `tests` array to include `"getusermedia"`:

```
modernizr: {
    devFile: '<%= yeoman.app %>/components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
    outputFile: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
    extra: {
        'shiv' : true,
        'printshiv' : false,
        'load' : true,
        'mq' : false,
        'cssclasses' : true
    },
    extensibility: {
        'addtest': true,
        'prefixed': false,
        'teststyles': false,
        'testprops': false,
        'testallprops': false,
        'hasevents': false,
        'prefixes': false,
        'domprefixes': false
    },
    files: [
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
        '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/vendor/*'
    ],
    uglify: true,
    // Explicitly include the `getusermedia` test
    tests: ['getusermedia']
}
```

---

Currently, `grunt-modernizr` is at version 0.5.2. One significant change from the OP is that the `Modernizr` task is now a [multi-task](http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#multi-tasks).

### Adding community tests in 0.5.2

The [README](https://github.com/Modernizr/grunt-modernizr/tree/e23fb3d95feab1f3e168604f696b59b4a16dc7c2#optional) still offers two (optional) options of interest:

> **`tests` (Array)**
>
> Define any tests you want to implicitly include. Test names are lowercased, separated by underscores (if needed). Check out the full set of test options [here](https://github.com/Modernizr/modernizr.com/blob/775ee6c1b769d7685e711654a6166313b0641cbc/i/js/modulizr.js#L15-157).

And:

> **`matchCommunityTests` (Boolean)**
>
> When `parseFiles` = `true`, setting this boolean to true will attempt to match user-contributed tests. Check out the full set of community tests [here](https://github.com/Modernizr/grunt-modernizr/blob/e23fb3d95feab1f3e168604f696b59b4a16dc7c2/lib/customappr.js#L2-111)

With this information, we know that we can define the task as follows:

```
modernizr: {
    dist: {
        devFile: '<%= yeoman.app %>/components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
        outputFile: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
        extra: {
            'shiv' : true,
            'printshiv' : false,
            'load' : true,
            'mq' : false,
            'cssclasses' : true
        },
        extensibility: {
            'addtest': true,
            'prefixed': false,
            'teststyles': false,
            'testprops': false,
            'testallprops': false,
            'hasevents': false,
            'prefixes': false,
            'domprefixes': false
        },
        uglify: true,
        tests: ['getusermedia']
    }
}
```

Where setting the `tests` array to include `'getusermedia'` will always include the community `getusermedia` test.

### Automatically detecting community tests

(See [#67](https://github.com/Modernizr/grunt-modernizr/issues/67), [#85](https://github.com/Modernizr/grunt-modernizr/issues/85), [#86](https://github.com/Modernizr/grunt-modernizr/issues/86), [#87](https://github.com/Modernizr/grunt-modernizr/pull/87), and [#88](https://github.com/Modernizr/grunt-modernizr/pull/88).)

Automatic detection of community tests is buggy. It seems that regardless of what `matchCommunityTests` is set to, `false` or `true`, community tests that exist will be downloaded and included in the custom build. For example, this basic task config:

```
modernizr: {
    dist: {
        devFile: 'vendor/modernizr/modernizr.js',
        outputFile: 'js/modernizr.custom.js',
        uglify: false,
        files: {
            src: ['js/src/**/*.js']
        }
    }
}
```

And this simple JS file:

```
;(function (
    window,
    document,
    Modernizr
) {
    if (Modernizr.touch) {}
    if (Modernizr.cookies && Modernizr.cors && Modernizr.gamepad) {}
}(
    window,
    window.document
    Modernizr
));
```

Results in a [custom build that *does* include tests for `cookies`, `cors`, and `gamepad`](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9c15a3bca8f2a65f919c): [download link](http://modernizr.com/download/#-touch-shiv-cssclasses-cookies-cors-gamepad-load).